# Core Script File Accessable Through Angular Application

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-view

I am an Angular newbie and running into an issue whereby my core script file is not being seen by my partials for some reason. I can see that the core file is working correcting outside my partials and views.

Here is my setup:

**index.html (App)**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="testapplication">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Test!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheets/theme/rocket_theme.less" />
  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- Core Theme Less -->
<script type="text/javascript">
      less = {
        env: "development",
        logLevel: 0,
        async: true
      };
</script>
</head>
<body class="">
     <!-- Start: Main -->
        <div id="main">
        <div ng-include src="'app/views/shared/top_header.html'"></div>
           <div ng-view></div>
        </div>
    <!-- End: Main -->

<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/jquery/dist/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Theme Core JS -->
 <script src="assets/javascripts/theme/custom.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/javascripts/theme/utility/utility.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/javascripts/theme/main.js"></script>


<!-- Application - Plugins -->
<script src="vendor/underscore/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/less/dist/less.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/holderjs/holder.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/hello/dist/hello.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/chartjs/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular - Resources -->
<script src="vendor/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/restangular/dist/restangular.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/ng-currency/dist/ng-currency.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/angular-utils-pagination/dirPagination.js"></script>

<!-- Angular - Application -->
<script src="assets/javascripts/angular/app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascripts/angular/routes/routes.js"></script>
<script src="assets/javascripts/angular/services/shared-properties.js">  </script>

<!-- Application - Controllers -->
<script src="assets/javascripts/angular/controllers/topHeader_ctrl.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Init Theme Core    
  Core.init();
  console.log('init');
 });
 </script>

 </body> 

 </html>
```

If I initialize the core script file within a controller, then it only works for that particular controller:

**Top Header Controller**

```
app.controller('HeaderCtrl',   function($scope,$http,sharedProperties,Restangular) {

Core.init();//works but only for this controller

$scope.gotoUrl = function(url){
        window.location.href = "#/" + url;
    }

});
```

I am needing to be able to initialize the Core a single time so that it is accessible to every part of my application.

**main.js**

```
'use strict';
/*! main.js - v0.1.1
* http://admindesigns.com/
* Copyright (c) 2015 Admin Designs;*/

/* Core theme functions required for
 * most of the themes vital functionality */
 var Core = function(options) {

// Variables
var Body = $('body');


 // SideMenu Functions
  var runSideMenu = function(options) {

  // If sidebar is fixed init custom scrollbar plugin
  // if ($('#sidebar_left.affix').length && !$('body').hasClass('sb-l-m')) {
  //    $('.sidebar-left-content').scroller();
  // }     

  // Sidebar state naming conventions:
  // "sb-l-o" - SideBar Left Open
  // "sb-l-c" - SideBar Left Closed
  // "sb-l-m" - SideBar Left Minified
  // Same naming convention applies to right sidebar

  // SideBar Left Toggle Function
  var sidebarLeftToggle = function() {

     // We check to see if the the user has closed the entire
     // leftside menu. If true we reopen it, this will result
     // in the menu resetting itself back to a minified state.
     // A second click will fully expand the menu.
     if (Body.hasClass('sb-l-c') && options.collapse === "sb-l-m") {
        Body.removeClass('sb-l-c');
      }

     // Toggle sidebar state(open/close)
     Body.toggleClass(options.collapse).removeClass('sb-r-o').addClass('sb-r-c');

     triggerResize();
  };

  // SideBar Right Toggle Function
  var sidebarRightToggle = function() {

     // toggle sidebar state(open/close)
     if (options.siblingRope === true && !Body.hasClass('mobile-view') &&  Body.hasClass('sb-r-o')) {
        Body.toggleClass('sb-r-o sb-r-c').toggleClass(options.collapse);
     }
     else {
        Body.toggleClass('sb-r-o sb-r-c').addClass(options.collapse);
     }

     triggerResize();
  };

  // Sidebar Left Collapse Entire Menu event
  $('.sidebar-toggle-mini').on('click', function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     // Close Menu
     Body.addClass('sb-l-c');
     triggerResize();

     // After animation has occured we toggle the menu.
     // Upon the menu reopening the classes will be toggled
     // again, effectively restoring the menus state prior
     // to being hidden 
     if (!Body.hasClass('mobile-view')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           Body.toggleClass('sb-l-m sb-l-o');
        }, 250);
     }
   });

  // Check window size on load
  // Adds or removes "mobile-view" class based on window size
  var sbOnLoadCheck = function() {
     // Check Body for classes indicating the state of Left and Right Sidebar.
     // If not found add default sidebar settings(sidebar left open, sidebar right closed).
     if (!$('body.sb-l-o').length && !$('body.sb-l-m').length && !$('body.sb-l-c').length) {
        $('body').addClass(options.sbl);
     }
     if (!$('body.sb-r-o').length && !$('body.sb-r-c').length) {
        $('body').addClass(options.sbr);
     }

     // If window is < 1080px wide collapse both sidebars and add ".mobile-view" class
     if ($(window).width() < 1080) {
        Body.removeClass('sb-r-o').addClass('mobile-view sb-l-m sb-r-c');
     }
  };

  // Check window size on resize
  // Adds or removes "mobile-view" class based on window size
  var sbOnResize = function() {
     // If window is < 1080px wide collapse both sidebars and add ".mobile-view" class
     if ($(window).width() < 1080 && !Body.hasClass('mobile-view')) {
        Body.removeClass('sb-r-o').addClass('mobile-view sb-l-m sb-r-c');
     } else if ($(window).width() > 1080) {
        Body.removeClass('mobile-view');
     } else {
        return;
     }
  };

  // Most CSS menu animations are set to 300ms. After this time
  // we trigger a single global window resize to help catch any 3rd 
  // party plugins which need the event to resize their given elements
  var triggerResize = function() {

     // If sidebar is fixed init custom scrollbar plugin
     if ($('#sidebar_left.affix').length && $('body').hasClass('sb-l-m')) {
        $('.sidebar-left-content').scroller('destroy');
     }     


     setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize');
     }, 300)
  };

  // Functions Calls
  sbOnLoadCheck();
  $("#toggle_sidemenu_l").click(sidebarLeftToggle);
  $("#toggle_sidemenu_r").click(sidebarRightToggle);

  // Attach debounced resize handler
  var rescale = function() {
     sbOnResize();
  }
  var lazyLayout = _.debounce(rescale, 300);
  $(window).resize(lazyLayout);


  // 2. LEFT USER MENU TOGGLE

  // Find user menu item length 
  var usermenuItems = $('.user-menu').find('a');

  // Toggle open the user menu
  $('.sidebar-menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     // Toggle Class to signal state change
     $('.user-menu').toggleClass('usermenu-open').slideToggle('fast');

     // If menu is closed apply animation    
     if ($('.user-menu').hasClass('usermenu-open')) {
        usermenuItems.addClass('animated fadeIn');
     }

  });

  // 3. LEFT MENU LINKS TOGGLE
  $('.sidebar-menu li a.accordion-toggle').click(function(e) {

     // Any menu item with the accordion class is a dropdown submenu. Thus we prevent default actions
     e.preventDefault();

     // Any menu item with the accordion class is a dropdown submenu. Thus we prevent default actions
     if ($('body').hasClass('sb-l-m') && !$(this).parents('ul.sub-nav').length) {
        return;
     }

     // Any menu item with the accordion class is a dropdown submenu. Thus we prevent default actions
     if (!$(this).parents('ul.sub-nav').length) {
        $('a.accordion-toggle.menu-open').next('ul').slideUp('fast', 'swing', function() {
           $(this).attr('style', '').prev().removeClass('menu-open');
        });
     }
     // Any menu item with the accordion class is a dropdown submenu. Thus we prevent default actions
     else {
        var activeMenu = $(this).next('ul.sub-nav');
        var siblingMenu = $(this).parent().siblings('li').children('a.accordion-toggle.menu-open').next('ul.sub-nav')

        activeMenu.slideUp('fast', 'swing', function() {
           $(this).attr('style', '').prev().removeClass('menu-open');
        });
        siblingMenu.slideUp('fast', 'swing', function() {
           $(this).attr('style', '').prev().removeClass('menu-open');
        });
     }

     // Now we expand targeted menu item, add the ".open-menu" class
     // and remove any left over inline jQuery animation styles
     if (!$(this).hasClass('menu-open')) {
        $(this).next('ul').slideToggle('fast', 'swing', function() {
           $(this).attr('style', '').prev().toggleClass('menu-open');
        });
     }

  });
  }


 // jQuery Helper Functions
 var runHelpers = function() {

  // Disable selection
  $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
     return this
        .attr('unselectable', 'on')
        .css('user-select', 'none')
        .on('selectstart', false);
  };

  // Test for IE, Add body class if version 9
  function msieversion() {
       var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
       var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
       if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) { 
          var ieVersion = parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie)));
          if (ieVersion === 9) {$('body').addClass('no-js ie' + ieVersion);}
          return ieVersion;
       }
       else { return false; }
  }
  msieversion();

  // Clean up helper that removes any leftover
  // animation classes on the primary content container
  // If left it can cause z-index and visibility problems
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('#content').removeClass('animated fadeIn');
  },800);

  }

   // Delayed Animations
   var runAnimations = function() {

  // Add a class after load to prevent css animations
  // from bluring pages that have load intensive resources
  setTimeout(function() {
     $('body').addClass('onload-check');
  }, 100);

  // Delayed Animations
  // data attribute accepts delay(in ms) and animation style
  // if only delay is provided fadeIn will be set as default
  // eg. data-animate='["500","fadeIn"]'
  $('.animated-delay[data-animate]').each(function() {
     var This = $(this)
     var delayTime = This.data('animate');
     var delayAnimation = 'fadeIn';

     // if the data attribute has more than 1 value
     // it's an array, reset defaults 
     if (delayTime.length > 1 && delayTime.length < 3) {
        delayTime = This.data('animate')[0];
        delayAnimation = This.data('animate')[1];
     }

     var delayAnimate = setTimeout(function() {

        This.removeClass('animated-delay').addClass('animated ' + delayAnimation)
           .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
              This.removeClass('animated ' + delayAnimation);
           });

     }, delayTime);
  });

  // "In-View" Animations
  // data attribute accepts animation style and offset(in %)
  // eg. data-animate='["fadeIn","40%"]'
  $('.animated-waypoint').each(function(i, e) {
     var This = $(this);
     var Animation = This.data('animate');
     var offsetVal = '35%';

     // if the data attribute has more than 1 value
     // it's an array, reset defaults 
     if (Animation.length > 1 && Animation.length < 3) {
        Animation = This.data('animate')[0];
        offsetVal = This.data('animate')[1];
     }

     var waypoint = new Waypoint({
        element: This,
        handler: function(direction) {
           console.log(offsetVal)
           if (This.hasClass('animated-waypoint')) {
              This.removeClass('animated-waypoint').addClass('animated ' + Animation)
                 .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
                    This.removeClass('animated ' + Animation);
                 });
           }
        },
        offset: offsetVal
     });
  });

  }

   // Header Functions
   var runHeader = function() {

  // Searchbar - Mobile modifcations
  $('.navbar-search').on('click', function(e) {
     var This = $(this);
     var searchForm = This.find('input');
     var searchRemove = This.find('.search-remove');

     // Don't do anything unless in mobile mode
     if (!$('body.mobile-view').length) { return; }

     // Open search bar and add closing icon if one isn't found
     This.addClass('search-open');
     if (!searchRemove.length) {
        This.append('<div class="search-remove"></div>'); 
     }

     // Fadein remove btn and focus search input on animation complete
     setTimeout(function() {
        This.find('.search-remove').fadeIn();
        searchForm.focus();
        searchForm.one('keydown', function() {
           $(this).val('');
        });
     },330)

     // If remove icon clicked close search bar
     if ($(e.target).attr('class') == 'search-remove') {
        This.removeClass('search-open'); 
        This.find('.search-remove').remove();
     }

  });

  // custom animation for header content dropdown
  if ($('.dropdown-item-slide').length) {
     $('.dropdown-item-slide').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function() {
        var This = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
           This.addClass('slide-open');
        }, 20);
     });
     $('.dropdown-item-slide').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('slide-open');
     });
  }

  // Init jQuery Multi-Select for navbar user dropdown
  if ($("#user-status").length) {
     $('#user-status').multiselect({
        buttonClass: 'btn btn-default btn-sm',
        buttonWidth: 100,
        dropRight: false
     });
  }
  if ($("#user-role").length) {
     $('#user-role').multiselect({
        buttonClass: 'btn btn-default btn-sm',
        buttonWidth: 100,
        dropRight: true
     });
  }

  // Persistent tooltips. Use this class to prevent a menu
  // dropdown from closing when clicking content inside of it
  if ($('.dropdown-menu.dropdown-persist').length) {
     $('.dropdown-menu.dropdown-persist').on('click', function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var Target = $(e.target);

        // stopping event propagation will also disable multiselects from working
        // in areas such as the user menu dropdown. This helps correct that
        function closeMulti() {
           Target.parents('.dropdown-persist').find('.btn-group').each(function() {
              if ($(this).children('.multiselect').length) {
                 $(this).removeClass('open');
              }
           });
        };

        if (Target.hasClass('multiselect') || Target.parent().hasClass('multiselect')) {
           closeMulti();
           Target.parents('.btn-group').toggleClass('open');
        } else {
           closeMulti()
        }
     });
  }

  // Sliding Topbar Metro Menu
  var menu = $('#topbar-dropmenu');
  var items = menu.find('.metro-tile');
  var metroBG = $('.metro-modal');

  // Toggle menu and active class on icon click
  $('.topbar-menu-toggle').on('click', function() {

     menu.slideToggle(230).toggleClass('topbar-menu-open');
     $(items).addClass('animated animated-short fadeInDown').css('opacity', 1);

     // Create Modal for hover effect
     if (!metroBG.length) {
        metroBG = $('<div class="metro-modal"></div>').appendTo('body');
     }
     setTimeout(function() {
        metroBG.fadeIn();
     }, 380);

   });

  // If modal is clicked close menu
  $('body').on('click', '.metro-modal', function() {
     metroBG.fadeOut('fast');
     setTimeout(function() {
        menu.slideToggle(150).toggleClass('topbar-menu-open');
     }, 250);
  });
  }




    // Tray related Functions
   var runTrays = function() {

  // Match height of tray with the height of body
  var trayMatch = $('.tray[data-tray-height="match"]');
  if (trayMatch.length) {

     // Loop each tray and set height to match body
     trayMatch.each(function() {
        var Height = $('body').height();
        $(this).height(Height);
     });

  };

  // Debounced resize handler
  var rescale = function() {
     if ($(window).width() < 1000) {
        Body.addClass('tray-rescale');
     }
     else {Body.removeClass('tray-rescale tray-rescale-left tray-rescale-right');}
  }
  var lazyLayout = _.debounce(rescale, 300);

  if (!Body.hasClass('disable-tray-rescale')) {
     // Rescale on window resize
     $(window).resize(lazyLayout);

     // Rescale on load
     rescale();
  }

  }

   // Form related Functions
   var runFormElements = function() {

  // Init Jquery Sortable, if present
  if ($(".sortable").length) {
     $(".sortable").sortable();
     $(".sortable").disableSelection();
  }

  var Tooltips = $("[data-toggle=tooltip]");

  // Init Bootstrap tooltips, if present 
  if (Tooltips.length) {
     if (Tooltips.parents('#sidebar_left')) {
        Tooltips.tooltip({
           container: $('body'),
           template: '<div class="tooltip tooltip-white" role="tooltip"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
        });
     } else {
        Tooltips.tooltip();
     }
  }

  // Init Bootstrap Popovers, if present 
  if ($("[data-toggle=popover]").length) {
     $('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
  }

  // Init Bootstrap persistent tooltips. This prevents a
  // popup from closing if a checkbox it contains is clicked
  $('.dropdown-menu .dropdown-persist').click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Prevents a dropdown menu from closing when a navigation
  // menu it contains is clicked (panel/tab menus)
  $('.dropdown-menu .nav-tabs li a').click(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     event.stopPropagation();
     $(this).tab('show')
  });

  // if btn has ".btn-states" class we monitor it for user clicks. On Click we remove
  // the active class from its siblings and give it to the button clicked.
  // This gives the button set a menu like feel or state
  if ($('.btn-states').length) {
     $('.btn-states').click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
     });
  }
  }
 return {
  init: function(options) {

     // Set Default Options
     var defaults = {
        sbl: "sb-l-o", // sidebar left open onload 
        sbr: "sb-r-c", // sidebar right closed onload

        collapse: "sb-l-m", // sidebar left collapse style
        siblingRope: true
        // Setting this true will reopen the left sidebar
        // when the right sidebar is closed
     };

     // Extend Default Options.
     var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

     // Call Core Functions
     runHelpers();
     runAnimations();
     runSideMenu(options);
     runTrays();
     runFormElements();
     runHeader();
  }

  }
}();

// Global Library of Theme colors for Javascript plug and play use  
var bgPrimary = '#4a89dc',
bgPrimaryL = '#5d9cec',
bgPrimaryLr = '#83aee7',
bgPrimaryD = '#2e76d6',
bgPrimaryDr = '#2567bd',
bgSuccess = '#70ca63',
bgSuccessL = '#87d37c',
bgSuccessLr = '#9edc95',
bgSuccessD = '#58c249',
bgSuccessDr = '#49ae3b',
bgInfo = '#3bafda',
bgInfoL = '#4fc1e9',
bgInfoLr = '#74c6e5',
bgInfoD = '#27a0cc',
bgInfoDr = '#2189b0',
bgWarning = '#f6bb42',
bgWarningL = '#ffce54',
bgWarningLr = '#f9d283',
bgWarningD = '#f4af22',
bgWarningDr = '#d9950a',
bgDanger = '#e9573f',
bgDangerL = '#fc6e51',
bgDangerLr = '#f08c7c',
bgDangerD = '#e63c21',
bgDangerDr = '#cd3117',
bgAlert = '#967adc',
bgAlertL = '#ac92ec',
bgAlertLr = '#c0b0ea',
bgAlertD = '#815fd5',
bgAlertDr = '#6c44ce',
bgSystem = '#37bc9b',
bgSystemL = '#48cfad',
bgSystemLr = '#65d2b7',
bgSystemD = '#2fa285',
bgSystemDr = '#288770',
bgLight = '#f3f6f7',
bgLightL = '#fdfefe',
bgLightLr = '#ffffff',
bgLightD = '#e9eef0',
bgLightDr = '#dfe6e9',
bgDark = '#3b3f4f',
bgDarkL = '#424759',
bgDarkLr = '#51566c',
bgDarkD = '#2c2f3c',
bgDarkDr = '#1e2028',
bgBlack = '#283946',
bgBlackL = '#2e4251',
bgBlackLr = '#354a5b',
bgBlackD = '#1c2730',
bgBlackDr = '#0f161b';
```

Comment: could you give some idea about what kind of code is there in core libraries? are you attaching DOM events, modifying css attributes   and rewriting DOM?

Comment: Added main.js (Core) for reference

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing lot of DOM rewriting and attribute manipulation in core libraries then it is not going to work in either case when new view is rendered. Even putting it outside the controller will work for first controller loaded.

You can do something like

```
function SomeController($scope) {
   $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){Core.init();});
}
```

You will have to do it in each controller.

A better practice is to write a directive.

EDIT:
SO here is a thumb rule. If core files are not touching angular views then you are better off keeping it outside otherwise you will have to do it as mentioned above

EDIT2: my suggestion based on now added main.js. It has rules that applies to generic elements like dropdown. So I would suggest you go the angular way

Comment: When you refer to 'angular way', you are referencing creating a directive?

Comment: here by angular way I mean either the directive way or the `viewContentLoaded` event but not in `document.ready` "outside" angular